# How to disable a VirtualBox network interface using a command-line?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-interface

When list virtual network interfaces, some of them are not anymore needed:

```
vboxnet1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 
vboxnet8: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:08 
vboxnet9: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:09 
vboxnet11: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0b 
vboxnet12: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0c
```

How can I make them disable them for good?

Comment: how did you list them?

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea, you can use the `ip addr` command

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out VirtualBox comes natively with a special command dedicated to this need:

e.g. to remove the network interface vboxnet0, 
execute the following command

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0
```

Comment: Via a script if there are dozens of them: `for i in {1..130}; do VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet$i ; done` (replace 130 as needed, this removes vbnoxnet1 to vboxnet130).

Comment: Taht should have been `{0..130}` - Virtualbox starts numbering interfaces at zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Using GUI,**

Open Virtualbox, click File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Network, remove Vboxnet#

[image: Host-only Network]

**Using command line,**

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet#
```

(replace the '#' accordingly, in your case 1, 8, 9, 11, 12)